# Sync PDF reading position across Windows, iOS, Android

Tags: windows, android, ios, cross-platform, pdf-viewer

I'm looking for a PDF reader for Windows 10, Android, and iPad that syncs the reading position across devices. This means that when you stop reading at a certain point on one device, opening that file on a different device would immediately bring you to that same page or part of that page that you left off on. It could be the same app across all devices, or different apps, but it needs to sync the last page you left off on.

Also, it must have the ability to highlight text. Other basic annotation features like adding notes/comments or text or inked drawings are nice, but not as important.

The cost across the three platforms should be less than $20.

Currently, I'm using Xodo on Windows and Android, and PDF Expert on iOS 12, with the PDF file stored in Google Drive. This is synced to my Android phone with DriveSync, and PDF Expert on iOS has built-in Google Drive sync. There's no syncing of reading progress here, although usually I highlight enough that I can just scroll to the last place I highlighted and that does an okay job.